# How to remove an empty directory (btrfs filesystem)?

Tags: linux, files, btrfs

I'm using the experimental `btrfs` filesystem.

My directory looks like this:

```
 ls -la empytfolder
 total 4
 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 19. Mär 14:00 .
 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 298 19. Mär 13:59 ..
```

I try to removed it with `rm -rf emptyfolder` but it gives the error `rm: cannot remove directory: directory not empty?` How can I remove/delete my emptyfolder? Why do I have 4 files in this folder? I'm trying to delete it as a root user. My filesystem is btrfs.

`stat emptyfolder` gives me:

```
 Datei: „emptyfolder“
 Größe: 0           Blöcke: 0          EA Block: 4096   Verzeichnis
 Gerät: 21h/33d Inode: 256         Verknüpfungen: 1
 Zugriff: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
 Zugriff    : 2012-03-19 14:00:28.205205566 +0100
 Modifiziert: 2012-03-19 14:00:23.925025572 +0100
 Geändert   : 2012-03-19 14:00:23.925025572 +0100
 Geburt    : -
```

I've some problems with my system clock. Sometimes it's showing the wrong time.

```
$ lsof +D emptyfolder
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/user
/.gvfs Output information may be incomplete.
```

What is this gvfs-fuse-daemon? How can I delete it?

I've tried fuser -uv /dev/disk to no avail. There isn't any process accessing the folder. I've moved the folder to tmp.

Comment: What is the output of `shopt -s dotglob nullglob; x=(*) ; echo "${#x[@]}"`? Also, "insgesamt" (total) is not the total number of files, but the total number of blocks, including indirect blocks.

Comment: A few questions: are you deleting them as root? Is the folder in use? Also, as far as my command of German goes, `insgesamt 4` means that there are 4 blocks in the folder, not zero.

Comment: shopt -s dotglob nullglob; x=(*) ; echo "${#x[@]}" gives 0 in that folder?

Comment: @WojtekRzepala - "insgesamt" is "total", ie "total blocks", not total files.

Comment: @David - Then there really is nothing in the folder except for the standard `.` and `..` hardlinks. What is the output of `echo "$EUID"`?

Comment: @ChrisDown: echo "$EUID" gives 0?

Comment: Post the output of `stat emptyfolder` please.

Comment: Then you should have adequate permissions. Perhaps this is a race condition with another program.

Comment: can you try running `find epmtyfolder`? What's the output?

Comment: @rahmu: find emptyfolder gives me emptyfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cd`'ing out of the emptydir and running `lsof +D /path/to/emptydir` on it to see what has it open. Depending what the directory is and how its used, perhaps something is opening and closing the directory very fast and you just happen to catch it when it doesn't have anything in it when running ls but does have something when running `rm -fr emptydir`.  It shouldn't make any difference in this case, but try also running `rmdir emptydir`.

The total number at the top of your `ls` output (I guess insgesamt meants total?) does indicate an empty directory.

I think knowing the filesystem type may be helpful too. You probably also want to run `fsck` on it and see if that helps.

Comment: My filesystem is btrfs.

Comment: lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/user
 /.gvfs Output information may be incomplet

Comment: @deltraray: lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/user /.gvfs Output information may be incomplete. I've moved the folder to tmp. But the problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 5):

[Btrfs FAQ - I cannot delete an empty directory:](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Problem_FAQ#I_cannot_delete_an_empty_directory)

> **First case**, if you get:
>
> ```
> rmdir: failed to remove ‘emptydir’: Operation not permitted
> ```
>
> then this is probably because "emptydir" is actually a subvolume.
>
> You can check whether this is the case with:
>
> ```
> btrfs subvolume list -a /mountpoint
> ```
>
> To delete the subvolume you'll have to run:
>
> ```
> btrfs subvolume delete emptydir
> ```
>
> **Second case**, if you get:
>
> ```
> rmdir: failed to remove ‘emptydir’: Directory not empty
> ```
>
> then you may have an empty directory with a non-zero i_size.
>
> You can check whether this is the case with:
>
> ```
> stat -c %s emptydir
> 3196         <-- unexpected non-zero size
> ```
>
> Running `btrfs check` on that (unmounted) filesystem will confirm the
>   issue and list other problematic directories (if any).
>
> You will get a similar output (excerpt):
>
> ```
> checking fs roots
> root 5 inode 557772 errors 200, dir isize wrong
> root 266 inode 24021 errors 200, dir isize wrong ...
> ```
>
> Such errors should be fixable with `btrfs check --repair` provided you
>   run a recent enough version of btrfs-progs.
>
> Note that `btrfs check --repair` should not be used lightly as in some
>   cases it can make a problem worse instead of fixing anything.

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar symptoms with a btrfs partition and

```
btrfs check --repair /dev/sdXY
```

fixed the problem for me. The found errors were of the form:

```
root X inode Y errors 200, dir isize wrong
```

and

```
root X inode Y errors 80, file extent overlap
```

The second kind of error stayed even after the repair though, which has started worrying me.

Comment: This fixed my problem on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem with a orphaned directory on a ReadyNAS box. Share wasn't visible in GUI anymore but directory underneath /data was existent so far. So I wanted to remove this folder but rmdir doesn't work.

I deleted snapshot by snapshot

```
cd /data
btrfs subvolume delete ./VirtualBox1/.snapshots/309/snapshot
...
btrfs subvolume delete ./VirtualBox1/.snapshots/2/snapshot
btrfs subvolume delete ./VirtualBox1/.snapshots/1/snapshot
btrfs subvolume delete ./VirtualBox1/.snapshots
```

After deleting all snapshots I was able to remove the "folder" itself

```
btrfs subvolume delete ./VirtualBox1
```